# mysql error creating transaction in event

Tags: mysql

I'm new to using events an transactions. What i need is to combine these two sets of code resulting in moving old data to a history table.
What is wrong with the code?
Tried many different syntaxes but error is:
"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''History'
ON SCHEDULE AT TIMESTAMP '2016-10-22 16:00:00' DO START TRA' at line 1"

```
DELIMITER !!
CREATE EVENT 'History'
ON SCHEDULE AT TIMESTAMP '2016-10-22 16:00:00'
DO
START TRANSACTION;
set @N := (now());
INSERT INTO ss_log_history select * from ss_log where tid < date_sub(@N,INTERVAL 15 DAY);
DELETE FROM ss_log WHERE tid < date_sub(@N,INTERVAL 15 DAY);
COMMIT;
END !!
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I still do not get it. As you should know one can be starring at code for hours without finding the error. Therefor i polite ask for help! That duplicate has not same syntax

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quote `'` around event name. It should be

```
CREATE EVENT History
```

Refer [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html) for more information

Comment: That gives next error. Like I said, have tried a lot

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set @N := (now());
INSERT INTO ss_log_history select * from ss_log where tid < ' at line 5